# PHP handling SQL error

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm adding error handling to my PHP 5.5.19 code:

```
function customError($errno, $errstr) {
  switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "custom error<br />";
        echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />";
        break;

    default:
        echo "this is default<br />";
        break;
  }
}

set_error_handler("customError", E_USER_ERROR);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM unexisting_table";
mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

The problem is that the `customError` handler is not triggered on this SQL error (the table doesn't exist). I would like to be able to log these SQL errors.

> An alternative might be to check the length of mysql_error and if it means it is sql error then simple store the sql error:

```
if (strlen(mysql_error()) > 0) throw new TestException(mysql_error());
```

My goal is to have exceptions, runtime errors, database errors stored in the system.

Comment: STOP USING mysql_* it's not more supported !

Comment: not more supported? from my understanding it is still supported but will be removed in future versions. Am I wrong or?

Comment: it's vulnerable to many attacks, no more supported in current PHP version... yo best do to use mysqli_* it will cost you a simple **i**

Comment: hmm, I tried to convert to mysqli a month ago and ran into issues like:
more than 'max_user_connections' active connections, so I reverted back to mysql_*

I'll do some reseach to see if find a solution to that problem

My code consist of object oriented PHP, where all classes inherit from a class containing database connection. So in parent constructor the database connection is made. Beside this my code has several static methods and each creates it's own database connection

Comment: mysql_* has never thrown PHP errors/exceptions. Given that you want to store PHP errors in a database, do you really also want to capture data errors?

Comment: It would be nice to store database errors in the database, but it is not paramount important. It could also be database connection error, which means I cannot connect to database to store the error.